# I cannot figure out the foreach

Tags: php, foreach

I am trying to set up a mxl product feed using php but this is all new to me and I am hoping someone can help.  I have attached my current code which list's the product id's that have multiple sku's separately.

The output looks like this:

> Product_ID 1 
>   SKU 1234 
>   Product_ID1
>   SKU12345

I am trying to get is to look like this using the foreach

> Product_ID 1
>   SKU 1234
>   SKU 12345

Here is my current code

```
while ($row = $st->fetch()) {

    $xml .= "\t\t\t<Product_ID>".$row['product_id']."</Product_ID>\r\n";
    $xml .= "\t\t\t<Manufacture>".$row['manufactures_name']."</Manufacture>\r\n";
    $xml .= "\t\t\t<Product_Name>".$row['product_name']."</Product_Name>\r\n";
    $xml .= "\t\t\t<Product_Category>".$row['product_type']."</Product_Category>\r\n";
    $xml .= "\t\t\t<SKU>".$row['sku']."</SKU>\r\n";
    $xml .= "\t\t\t<UPC>".$row['upc']."</UPC>\r\n";
    $xml .= "\t\t\t<Base_Price>".$row['base_price']."</Base_Price>\r\n";
    $xml .= "\t\t\t<QtyAvailable>".$row['quantity']."</QtyAvailable>\r\n";

}
```

I tried to add `foreach` here but I do not have a clue.

```
while ($row = $st->fetch()) 

    $xml .= "\t\t\t<Product_ID>".$row['product_id']."</Product_ID>\r\n";
        foreach ('product_id' == 'product_id');
           $xml .= "\t\t\t<SKU>".$row['sku']."</SKU>\r\n";

    $xml .= "\t\t\t<Manufacture>".$row['manufactures_name']."</Manufacture>\r\n";
    $xml .= "\t\t\t<Product_Name>".$row['product_name']."</Product_Name>\r\n";
    $xml .= "\t\t\t<Product_Category>".$row['product_type']."</Product_Category>\r\n";
    $xml .= "\t\t\t<UPC>".$row['upc']."</UPC>\r\n";
    $xml .= "\t\t\t<Base_Price>".$row['base_price']."</Base_Price>\r\n";
    $xml .= "\t\t\t<QtyAvailable>".$row['quantity']."</QtyAvailable>\r\n";
}
```

Comment: `foreach` syntax is `foreach (array_expression as $value)` as per http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php and not "comparison" `==`.

Comment: I believe the OP is confused about how to use a `foreach` due to having to fetch the next item each time. Although I'm not sure what is wrong with using a `while` as it's commonly used to get row information from a database.

Comment: Yeah, that's not how you use `foreach`. Do a `var_dump($row)` and add that to your question so we can see the data you're working on. Also, consider using [simplexml](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) to build your XML. Or [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: `foreach ('product_id' == 'product_id');` You can do better!

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to generate XML, may I suggest you use PHP's SimpleXML library as it gives you much more flexibility, and reads much cleaner. For documentation see http://php.net/simplexml.

Example from the docs:

```
<?php

include 'example.php';

$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
$sxe->addAttribute('type', 'documentary');

$movie = $sxe->addChild('movie');
$movie->addChild('title', 'PHP2: More Parser Stories');
$movie->addChild('plot', 'This is all about the people who make it work.');

$characters = $movie->addChild('characters');
$character  = $characters->addChild('character');
$character->addChild('name', 'Mr. Parser');
$character->addChild('actor', 'John Doe');

$rating = $movie->addChild('rating', '5');
$rating->addAttribute('type', 'stars');

echo $sxe->asXML();

?>
```